# fecthAll() function returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to var_dump() everything from my database it just returns an emtpy array : array(0) { }

```
<?php

try{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;db=info_bk' , 'root' , '');
} catch (Exception $eroare){
  die('Could not connect because of :  ' . $eroare);
}


$statement = $pdo->prepare('select * from benefit_keys');
$statement -> execute();
var_dump($statement->fetchAll());
?>
```

I expect to dump all the arrays from the database table.

Comment: is your database contains values or not , check it?

Comment: Are you sure you have data in this table ? Not sur about the `db` key in the DSN, I always used `dbname`. Avoid spaces around the arrow: `$statement->execute();`. Also, as there's no parameter in this query, you could use PDO's `query` method.

Comment: yes i have data in the table

Comment: It worked with dbname. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: thats one off the reasons you should always enable PHP in "debugging" mode while programming..If you would have you would have directly known MySQL needs to have a "working" database..